# Is there a C# SecureString equivalent in C++?

Tags: c#, c++, securestring

I have a SecureString in my C# code that I need to pass into a DLL. I would prefer to not do a Marshalling as it seems that when this occurs the SecureString is unencrypted (and hence not secure anymore). So the question is whether or not there is a C# SecureString equivalent in C++ so that I can pass the SecureString from my C# code into the C++ DLL ... or if there is a better/different way such that I do not need to unencrypt the SecureString to pass it to the DLL.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508082/how-is-a-securestring-marshalled-to-unmanaged-code

Comment: You are only going to be able to dispatch that as plain text, perhaps look at using ProtectedData.Protect in C# and CryptUnprotectData in C++, both use the DPAPI

Comment: @Ralf I specifically said I was trying to avoid marshaling.

Comment: I did not check but i was under the impression that you get a still crypted string from Marshalling that you could decrypt via RtlDecryptMemory in c++. But i might be wrong. Docu for the Marshal class isn't clear about that. Atleast it doesn't specify explicitly that it does decrypt the string.

Comment: [*"... Each of these methods creates a clear-text string in unmanaged memory"*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx#interop)

Comment: SecureString solves a problem with System.String being immutable and managed code using a garbage collector that moves objects.  None of these concerns can apply to C++, it is never a problem to scrub the string content in that language.

Comment: @HansPassant that is true ... but my question is how to get the SecureString from C# to C++ securely (without marshaling ... because this decrypts it ... so that is why I am wondering if there is a mapping of the SecureString type to C++)

Comment: Interop with C++ always requires marshaling.  That's what the Marshal.SecureStringToXxx() methods do.  That it decrypts the string is a feature, not a bug.  And not a problem because the Xxx types can always be scrubbed.

Comment: I'm just surprised there isn't a way to just pass it through. Or without decrypting it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your  C++ compiler target the Common Language Runtime (CLR), you can use the same `SecureString` implementation.

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Security;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
   // Define the string value to assign to a new secure string.
   Char chars[4] = { 't', 'e', 's', 't' };
   // Instantiate the secure string.
   SecureString^ testString = gcnew SecureString();
   // Assign the character array to the secure string.
   for each (Char ch in chars)
   {
      testString->AppendChar(ch);
   }   
   // Display secure string length.
   Console::WriteLine("The length of the string is {0} characters.", 
                        testString->Length);

   delete testString;
   return 0;
}
// The example displays the following output:
//      The length of the string is 4 characters 4 characters
```