# What is C# SecureCode equivalent in C++?

Tags: c#, c++, security, secure-coding

We have application written in native C++ , COM , MFC. There are some XML strings in this application which needs to be kept confidential. Exploring option in C++ but could not find anything as equivalent as SecureString in C#. Anyidea how this can be achieved in C++. 
      Please note that don't have option to use managed C++ as it is legacy code written in native C++

Comment: Strings in c++ aren't immutable so what feature of SecureString are you missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a C# SecureString equivalent in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34067372/is-there-a-c-sharp-securestring-equivalent-in-c)

Comment: Answer provided to the duplicate question is on managed C++ , This question is for native C++ , I don't have option of managed C++ as code is legacy

Answer (score 0):

**C++ nativly does not support such a functionallity** but you can either create your own secure string type or use libaries. A open source libary providing a secure string is [SecureString](https://github.com/alex-caelus/SecureString).